# Why min(d1, d2) has byref in argument for vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I noticed that if I do

a = min (b,c)

I often got a warning that both b and c must be double and not integer. That's because while double can be converted to integer on the fly, the other way around doesn't work.

And the reason why it should work is because b and c is passed by reference.

However, why?

min (b,c) simply takes the smaller value of b or c and return it into a

Why should the argument is passed by ref? The function doesn't change the value of it's parameter?

Comment: What call to `min` are you talking about? `Math.Min(double, double)`?

Comment: There is no such method in the .NET Framework that I can see so I'm guessing that you're looking at a method implemented by a third party and possibly implemented badly.  As @Enigmativity suggests, the `Math.Min` method, which is probably what you should be calling, is not implemented that way, which is clearly what you correctly expected should be the case.

Comment: Ups. I did implement this. Sorry. I thought it's vb.net stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set vb.net as the tag:

1. Min() function (Math.Min) is overloaded and can take arguments of the following types: byte, decimal, single, double, signed and unsigned integers of different sizes (2, 4 or 8 bytes)
2. Both arguments should be of the same type, otherwise implicit conversion will take place. Your statement "That's because while double can be converted to integer on the fly, the other way around doesn't work." is not accurate; see code below.
3. Your statement "And the reason why it should work is because b and c is passed by reference." is not true either; see code below.

This following code should compile and run fine:

```
Module VBModule

    Sub Main()
         Console.WriteLine(Math.Min(5.1, 4))
    End Sub

End Module
```